# В chart не отображается одни из линий перекрестия

Tags: cursor, position, диаграммы

Проблема в том, что по оси Y, отображается линия перекрестия, а по X -нет. В чём может быть проблема?

```
System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Cursor cursor = null;
        cursor = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorX;
        cursor.LineWidth = 2;
        cursor.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDot;
        cursor.LineColor = Color.Red;
        cursor.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;
        System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting.Cursor cursor1 = null;
        cursor1 = chart1.ChartAreas[0].CursorY;
        cursor1.LineWidth = 2;
        cursor1.LineDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.DashDot;
        cursor1.LineColor = Color.Red;
        cursor1.SelectionColor = Color.Yellow;
```